# How to use Scrapy FormRequest.from_response() method to submit a form?

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to parse some info from [this](http://www.zooroyal.de/muehldorfer-pferdeleckerli-bio-bronchial?c=6259) page and then reload the page with other options from the drop-down menu called "Packungsgröße". There are 3 options, so I am trying to scrape the same page for all the options.

I found out that I can use the form of `class="upprice_config"` and `POST` it with the correct data. I do not know exactly which data I need to supply, so I supply all I have. Then I call the same function for parsing.

Any way, it does not work the way I want. It does not give me any error and seems it executes the form submission, but I do not get the required page.

Here is my code:

```
... def parse_product(self, response):
120     sc_menu = response.xpath('//form[@class="upprice_config"]/div/select')
121         if sc_menu:
122             sel_name = sc_menu[0].xpath('@name').extract()[0]
124             for opt in sc_menu[0].xpath('option'):
126                 if opt.xpath('@selected'):
127                     selected = opt.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
129                     product['options'] = selected.strip()
130 
131                     yield product
132 
133                 # extract value
134                 value = opt.xpath('@value').extract()[0]
136                 # submit form for the new option
137                 self.submit_form(response, value, sel_name)
138         else:
139             product['options'] = ''
140 
141             yield product
142 
143 
144 # submit form for the new option
145 def submit_form(self, response, value, sel_name):
146     formdata = {'method': 'POST',
147                 'action': response.url,
148                 'value': value}
149     scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response(response, 
150                 formdata = formdata, 
151                 clickdata = {'name': sel_name},
152                 callback = self.parse_product)
```

Can somebody point me to what I am doing wrong here. If there is a better way to do it, please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using firefox try to install firebug and check what data website is posting

i can see they are posting option value

```
select class="form-control" onchange="this.form.submit();" name="group[1]">
  <option value="3"> 3kg </option>
  <option value="233" selected="selected"> 10kg </option>
  <option value="3603"> 25kg </option>
```

either you can post that data or i just checked you can Make get requests too

something like

```
http://www.zooroyal.de/muehldorfer-pferdeleckerli-bio-bronchial?c=6259&group[1]=233
http://www.zooroyal.de/muehldorfer-pferdeleckerli-bio-bronchial?c=6259&group[1]=3603
```

Comment: Good point about the `GET`. Thank you. I think, I need to post the request a little differently. Can I find those `POST` arguments in Chrome?

Comment: why not, just make a google query how to see network requests in chorme and you will find an answer ... if this answer is helpfull for you just mark it as an answer too

Comment: Thank you. I want to wait a little to see if there is somebody with another option for my case.

Comment: The form still does not work but your suggestion about the GET works fine.